# How can i watch for change in a angular directive with $translate

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Here's  [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/UGLjh/73/)

How can i watch for change in a directive? In this fiddle example using $translate to translate the content. Everything getting changed except the content in Directive.

HTML looks like this-

```
 <div ng-app='demo'>

<div name="info" ng-controller="myctrl">
    <label translate="TERMS_LABEL"></label>
    <h4 translate="ZIPCODE_LABEL"></h4>
    <p translate="LAST_NAME"></p>
   <terms-conditions conditions="TERMS_CONDITIONS" checked="checked"></terms-conditions> 
    <button type="submit"  ng-click="changeLanguage('de')" >Spanish</button>
     <button type="submit"  ng-click="changeLanguage('en')" >English</button>

     </div>
```

directive looks like

```
 demo.directive("termsConditions",['$translate',function($translate){
return {
    restrict:"E",
    scope:{
         checked:'='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr) { 
        $translate(attr.conditions)
        .then(function (translatedValue) {
            scope.conditions = translatedValue;
        });
    },
    template:
    "<div class='terms row'><span class='col-md-12'>{{conditions}}</span></div><br><input   
   type='checkbox' ng-model='checked'><span>Yes, I agree to the terms and condtions</span>"
}

}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't translate in the template like so?

http://jsfiddle.net/UGLjh/75/

```
demo.directive("termsConditions",['$translate',function($translate){
    return {
        restrict:"E",
        scope:{
             checked:'='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr) { 
            attr.$observe('conditions', function (untranslatedValue) {
                scope.conditions = untranslatedValue;
            });
        },
        template:
        "<div class='terms row'><span class='col-md-12'>{{conditions | translate}}</span></div><br><input type='checkbox' ng-model='checked'><span>Yes, I agree to the terms and condtions</span>"
    }

}]);
```

If you know that your attribute won't be interpolated need not use `$observe`; just stick it on the scope like so:

```
    link: function(scope, element, attr) { 
        scope.conditions = attr.conditions;
    },
```